# how to diplay ACF information in content single

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, advanced-custom-fields

i work on a wordpress project and i need to add information with acf in my template but i don't know why nothing display on the screen. i put my code in content-single.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxDoF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdEeq.png)

here the code add:

```
$id_event = get_field('evenement');
$public= get_field('public_cible_evenement',$id_event);
if ($public){
    echo $public;

}
```

Comment: have you checked your $id_event is getting right value or not? If not put the_ID(), as second parameter to $id_event variable. 
$id_event = get_field('evenement',the_ID());

Comment: I checked my $id_event, it's is empty.

Comment: how can i get the id with acf ?

Comment: $id_event=get_the_ID();
                        $id_session=get_field('session');
                        $id_speaker=get_field('speaker');
                        if (!empty($id_event)){

Comment: id_event work now by the other not

Comment: I have also checked no "evenement" field is there in the attached image. Have you put the 2nd parameter and then checked?

Comment: It works great. When you are getting empty value then just put the 2nd parameter "ID"